# How put zero prefix for Long value < 10 e.g for DB Id's?

Tags: java, identifier

can somebody give litle advice about how give a zero prefix for output of Id's less than 10.
For example i want show in output label a single id value which is type of Long in  DB is this value `4` but in output on some label i want show in form with leading zero so `04` i found some case but its about `int primitive type` so its there some casting what i cant solve,

so far i have this code:

```
public String getCode() {           
    PackageVersion packVer = BeanFactory.getHotelDAOService(PackageVersion.class).findOne(selectedDealerCodeId);
    if(packVer.getId() < 10){       
        String id = String.format("%0d", packVer.getId());
    }
    return id;
}
```

above this method dont work, If somebody knows better and suitable solution about this please let me here post, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this line:

```
String id = String.format("%0d", packVer.getId());
```

to

```
String id = String.format("%02d", packVer.getId());
```

This will make sure at least 2 spaces are used to print the number, and format will pad it with zeros to achieve this.
You can probably get rid of the `if` statement too, I don't think it does anything by looking at the code snippet.

Comment: thanks its work exactly what i want,yes you are right this `if` is absolutly not necessesary,totaly is suficient this simple format magic

Answer (score 1):

The format you are looking for is `%02d` but given the simplicity of what you are doing, you are better off with the following snippet:

```
if (packver.getId() < 10) {
  return "0" + packver.getID();
}
return "" + packver.getID();
```

The optimizer will do the right thing with this code behind the scenes, whereas the `format()` may fool it.

You have a serious bug in your code that `id` is not defined in the scope you return it, so that code won't even compile.  The general form is like this:

```
String id;
if (someCondition) {
  id = someValue;
} else {
  id = otherValue;
}

return id;
```

In your specific case, the if and the else clauses are the same, so you can get rid of the branch altogether.

```
return String.format("%02d", packver.getID());
```